# Python open FTP url and write to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

How can I open and FTP url and download it into a file. What I'm trying looks something like this:

```
from contextlib import closing
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'ftp://whatever.com/file.txt'
target_path = 'file.txt'

with closing(urlopen(url)) as source:
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as target:
        target.write(source)
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: 'addinfourl' does not support the buffer interface
```

Is there any simple way to make this work? Especially if I want to extend it, so that the file is extracted while it is downloaded?

Comment: What is `closing`? Presumably you want it to equate to the content of the FTP URL?

Comment: Apologies, I posted a louse code snippet. I've added import statements.

Answer (score 0):

The `write` requires object with buffer interface in particular `bytes`, but the `source` is actually `BufferedReader` (or `HTTPResonse` if http). To get bytes you need to call [`BufferedReader.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader.read)

```
from contextlib import closing
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'ftp://whatever.com/file.txt'
target_path = 'file.txt'

with closing(urlopen(url)) as source:
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as target:
        target.write(source.read())
```

Comment: That works, but as far as I understand it downloads the entire file into memory, and then writes it to disk, right? That is problematic for large files.

Comment: Yes, I can use that, but I was wondering if there is way to do this without writing manual loops.